# Click to Expand Text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a text "Click Me"

and a"P" tag  with limited view text option . is there any way with jquery to click the "Click me "  and Expand the Text . and again Click me to Hide . Sorry I am Not good at jQuery . Not finding way wo made it .

See live demo js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/7wKyj/

```
**HTML**
<div>Click me</div>

 <p>
  It is a long established fact that a reader
  will be distracted by the readable content of a 
  page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum 
  is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, 
  as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
  making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing 
 <p>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:100px;
 }
```

If can that will be Great .

Comment: look into slideUp() and slideDown() -http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/- and http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `toggleClass` (one of many options)

```
$("element").toggleClass("className");
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        $("#para").toggleClass("myClass");
    })
});
```

```css
p{
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     display: block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width:100px;
}

.myClass
{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickMe">Click me</div>

<p id="para" class="myClass">
   It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing 
<p>
```

Comment: Thanks this is very simple way to expand/collapse text